# Heatmaps.js Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, api, heatmap

im using the heatmaps.js library as well as the Google Maps API to display a map as well as a heatmap over the top. I have been able to display the map as well as query the database to obtain the data I need. The problem i'm having is getting the heatmap to display. I get the following two errors:

gmaps-heatmap.js:27 Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined

HeatMapsTest.php:41 Uncaught ReferenceError: HeatmapOverlay is not defined

The first error is in the library itself and the second error occurs in the code below:

```
<html>
    <head>  
        <style> 

        html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

        #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        }

        </style>


    </head>
  <body>

  <div id="map-canvas"></div>


<?php

//parameters for connecting to database
$servername = '';
$username = '';
$password = '';
$dbname = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully <br> ";

$sql = "SELECT LATITUDE,LONGITUDE FROM `crashes`";

$test = $conn->query($sql);

if ($test == true) {
echo "Query Worked!";
} else {
echo "Query Did Not Work";
} 

try{
    $db = $conn;
        $result = $db->query($sql);
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC) ) {
        $data[] = $row;
        }
    $db = NULL;
        $data_json = json_encode($data);
        /* echo "<br>";
        echo $data_json; */

        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
        }

?>

<script>

  function initMap() {

  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-37.8, 144.9);

  var myOptions = {
  zoom: 8,
  center: myLatlng
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);

        heatmap = new HeatmapOverlay(map,
          {
            // radius should be small ONLY if scaleRadius is true (or small radius is intended)
            "radius": 17,
            "maxOpacity": 1,
            // scales the radius based on map zoom
            "scaleRadius": false,
            // if set to false the heatmap uses the global maximum for colorization
            // if activated: uses the data maximum within the current map boundaries.
            //   (there will always be a red spot with useLocalExtremas true)
            "useLocalExtrema": true,
            // which field name in your data represents the lat - default "lat"
            latField: 'LATITUDE',
            // which field name in your data represents the lng - default "lng"
            lngField: 'LONGITUDE',
            // which field name in your data represents the data value - default "value"
            valueField: 'value'
          }
        );


        var testData = {
          max: 8,
          data : <?php echo $data_json; ?>
        };

        heatmap.setData(testData);

  }

  </script>


  <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>       
    <script src="heatmap.js-develop/build/heatmap.js"></script>
    <script src="heatmap.js-develop/plugins/gmaps-heatmap.js"></script> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: May be wrong but try to load other libraries with async defer flags too. Im thinking your code executed before heatmap loaded. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hmm that didnt seem to fix it :(

Answer (score 4):

You're calling `initMap()` callback as soon as Google Maps script is loaded, which may be before Heatmap.js library is loaded. Load Google maps synchronously and add a DOM loaded event listener to call your `initMap()` function only after all scripts have been loaded.

So replace this:

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&callback=initMap"></script>  
<script src="heatmap.js-develop/build/heatmap.js"></script>
<script src="heatmap.js-develop/plugins/gmaps-heatmap.js"></script>
```

With this:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY"></script>       
<script src="heatmap.js-develop/build/heatmap.js"></script>
<script src="heatmap.js-develop/plugins/gmaps-heatmap.js"></script>
<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    initMap();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure the heatmap.js file is loaded correctly, there is no typo in path or anything? Are there any other errors? Try getting another release of the library maybe?